# "Возводит в культ Золотого тельца и возносит ему хвалу"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, прописная-строчная

> Фрейд здесь указывает на факт, что принято считать: Моисей изображён
>   Микеланджело согласно тексту Ветхого Завета, книги Исхода (глава 32).
>   Народ, устав ждать Моисея, **возводит в культ Золотого тельца и возносит
>   ему хвалу.** А пророк, испросив у Господа спасения для неразумных и
>   получив **скрижали закона**, увидев празднества у фетиша, приходит в
>   ярость. Момент столкновения двух миров, сцена, в которой Моисей
>   приносит людям весть «о дне взыскания», согласно Библии, исполнена
>   неистовства. Источник утверждает, что пророк кинет наземь Слово Божье,
>   начертанное на скрижалях.

Золотой телец возможен с прописной?

Скрижали закона? Нашла: Скрижа́ли Заве́та, Скрижали свидетельства, скрижали Заповедей... Прописные-строчные скачут.

Кто-нибудь - откликнитесь по существу пересказа главы 32 книги Исхода!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Золотой телец - со строчной. И это логично. Поскольку прописная буква придала бы ему особый статус. Заметьте, с прописной буквы пишутся имена только святых, в том числе и БОГ. Золотой теленок - это культ, идол. Кстати, бог (языческий) тоже со строчной.

Что касается скрижалей. Согласно русскому орфографическому словарю "скрижали" со строчной. Правильно: скрижали Завета. В переводе нового мира библии (***Книга Исхода***)встречается "скрижали Свидетельств". Хотя в интернете встречаются две прописные.

Поэтому ориентируясь на аналогичное название, следует писать со строчной: **скрижали Закона.**

Comment: Про «скрижали откровения» вставлю слово: так в самой Книге Исхода.

Comment: Shampar, куда вставите?

Comment: В Ваше упоминание о Библии.

Answer (score 1):

> Фрейд здесь указывает на факт, что принято считать: Моисей изображён
>   Микеланджело согласно тексту Ветхого Завета, книги Исхода (глава 32).
>   Народ, устав ждать Моисея, возводит в культ Золотого тельца и возносит
>   ему хвалу. А пророк, испросив у Господа спасения для неразумных и
>   получив скрижали закона, увидев празднества у фетиша, приходит в
>   ярость. Момент столкновения двух миров, сцена, в которой Моисей
>   приносит людям весть «о дне взыскания», согласно Библии, исполнена
>   неистовства. Источник утверждает, что пророк кинет наземь Слово Божье,
>   начертанное на скрижалях.

Фрейд здесь указывает на тот факт, что Моисей изображён Микеланджело согласно Ветхозаветному тексту (Исх. Гл. 32): народ Израиля, уже не надеясь на его возвращение, руками Аарона создаёт литого тельца для поклонения. Испросив у пришедшего в ярость Господа спасения для неразумных и получив от Него скрижали откровения, Пророк сходит с горы. В момент столкновения двух миров, когда Моисей приносит идолопоклонникам весть «о дне взыскания», согласно Библии, он воспламенился гневом. Людям больно было смотреть в его сторону. Утверждается, что пророк «бросил из рук своих скрижали» оземь.